# Progress bar in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to make progress bar in angular. I started using angular mmat-stepper and my code is as follows::

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material'
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my html page::

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear] = "isLinear" #stepper>
   <mat-step [stepControl] = "firstFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup] = "firstFormGroup">
         <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter your name</ng-template>
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder = "Last name, First name" formControlName = "firstCtrl" required>
         </mat-form-field>
         <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step [stepControl] = "secondFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup] = "secondFormGroup">
         <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter your address</ng-template>
         <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder = "Address" formControlName = "secondCtrl" required>
         </mat-form-field>
         <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
         Details taken.
      <div>
         <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
         <button mat-button (click) = "stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
   </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

My component is as follows::

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Validators } from "@angular/forms";
export interface Food {
   value: string;
   display: string;
}
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'materialApp';   
   firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
   secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
   constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
         firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
      });
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
         secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
      });
   }
}
```

The output I am getting is something like this::

[image]

[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzYqC.png)

But I want to make progress bar something like this as shown in below image

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9hwK.jpg)

[image]

How can I make progress bar like shown in desired_output image?

Answer (score 0):

you may do that by modifying the selector (.mat-stepper-horizontal-line) in material design.

add this to your main style. (Change css based on the desire output)

```
.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

sample output
[image]

for the sample code you may see this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cxlnp

Hope this helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: after adding this css do I need to make any  changes to html page to apply this css?

Comment: No need it will override the horizontal line selector. just tweak it based on your desire layout. if you want to put image just add background-image on that.

Comment: and how can I write steps like details , desserts etc  near that triangle  as shown in image?

Comment: Instead of these small triangles can I get those big triangle as shown in image?

Comment: ohh sorry I thought you just need the arrow on the stepper. But anyway you may check it here for the code. [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cxlnp](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cxlnp)

Comment: you may do that also in css see my code i created a blue one just rotate it. Hope this help you :) cheers mate!

Comment: Hi , I am getting only a small triangle  by apply these css as mentioned by you. How can I get exactily same size triangle  as mentioned in my image?

Comment: you may modify the css based on what you want to achive